# state not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple code for valdiations my inputs in the state:

```
validateForm2: function () {
        var formIsValid = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.inputs.length; i++) {
            var currentInput = this.state.inputs[i];
            var inputValue = this.state[currentInput.name];
            if (!currentInput.validate(inputValue)) {
                formIsValid = false;
                this.makeInvalid(currentInput.name);
            }
        }

        return formIsValid;
    },
```

`makeInvalid` calls other method for showing error message:

```
 makeInvalid: function (elemName) {
   ...
   this.showValidationError(inputs[i].validateMessage);
   ...
}
```

This is a `showValidtionMessage`:

```
showValidationError: function (message) {
        var summary = this.state.validationSummary + message;
        this.setState({
            validationSummary: summary
        });            
    }
```

When I have two errors `showValidationError` is called twice and in the debugger I see that there are two different message come to the function, but `validationSummary` has only one message(the second). I don't know why. Also, I tried to write `console.log(this.state.validationSummary)` after `setState` and in the console I get empty string after the first call. Where is a error?

PS. I have read documentation and there is written that `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. May be is this the reason? if so how to rewrite my code?

Comment: Yeah, if you are calling `setState` twice in the same tick, all data will be merged. `this.state` is only updated at the end of the tick.

Comment: Do you know how to rewrite this? I don'thave any idea. `setInterval` is not good idea I think:)

Comment: Just build the complete error message in `validateForm2` and call `setState` after the loop?

Comment: Yeah, I think I can do this, I will build message after the loop, I have flag `isInvalid` in the state for input. Thanks for the direction. Could you write your comment as the answer and I will mark it?

Comment: @FelixKling: One more question, You wrote that all data will be merged. Does it mean that if in one tick I update state like that: `this.setState({text: this.state.text + 'text1'}); this.setState({this.state.text + 'text2'}) ` I will get `text1text2` in the end of the tick or not?

Comment: No, because `this.state.text` has still the old text from the previous tick. Also it's a shallow merge. `setState({foo: 42}); setState({foo: 21});` is equivalent to `setState({foo: 21});`.